# Can not execute some shell command from php

Tags: php, libraries, openssl

I want to execute phpcs commands from phpcode using shell_exec function. During execution it gives error `/usr/bin/php: relocation error: /usr/bin/php: symbol X509_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference`.
How can I solve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `libssl` library is broken. Try running:

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb3351000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f28feaf1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f28fe731000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f28fe52c000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f28fe315000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f28ff149000)
```

If your output shows file not found or point to an old version of `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`, you should reinstall `openssl`.

And if you compile php from source, please make sure you have `--with-openssl` option with correct place of `libssl` dir.

Comment: Congrats on 3k!